# Proof of Stationarity of dependent variable

Tags: stationarity, cointegration

I have a linear regression model of time series data where the model developer has found that the dependent variables is not stationary via ADF, KPSS and Phillips Perron tests. The developer claims that the two predictors are stationary in their level form. He then shows that the error term (residuals from the regression) is stationary via MacKinnon test. He then concludes that since all terms on the RHS (two predictors and error term) are stationary, therefore the dependent variable is stationary, even though it has been shown to be non-stationary. I believe the logic is circular and erroneous, or that he is trying to cite Engle-Granger cointegration theory incorrectly  since at least one of the series in cointegrated series has to I(d), where d>0. Am I right, and how do I disprove his argument?